# Trying to remove all children, receiving error #1009

Tags: actionscript-3, removechild

The idea with my setup is that I have an input text field and three separate buttons on stage. When you type something in the text field and press the input button, the text inside the field is added to an array.

When you press the display button the contents of the array are displayed on screen (each value of the array is displayed underneath the last value).

The final button is supposed to remove all the current values on the array, and clear all displayed values on screen. But I cannot get my code to work as intended, since I receive,

`TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.`

With this block of code:

```
import flash.text.TextField;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

var myArray:Array = new Array (""); 
var tf:TF;

btnInput.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, txtInput);

function txtInput(event:MouseEvent):void
{myArray.push(txtInput.text);}

btnDisplay.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, txtDisplay);

function txtDisplay(event:MouseEvent):void
{for (var i:int = 0; i < myArray.length; i++)
{var tf:TF = new TF();
tf.txt.text = myArray[i];
tf.y = 280 + (i * 25);
tf.x = 265; 
addChild(tf);
tf.name="test";}
}

btnClear.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, txtClear);

function txtClear(event:Event){
myArray.splice(1);
if (tf.numChildren != 0){
removeChild(getChildByName("test"));}
}
```

Alternatively, when I add

```
var tf:TF = new TF;
```

It removes only one displayed value on screen. Also I might add, that "TF" is a movie clip in the library that contains a dynamic text field that's instance name is txt. Is the problem only with the last button, or should I change something else as well? I don't know how to make this work as I want it to. I'm pretty new to coding so any tips or help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have an array of values, and not have an array of TFs? Rework this ASAP, your 1009 will likely disappear entirely.

Comment: tf is a movieClip symbol TF. How do I put them in an Array? myArray is for input text. So I have string in array. I don't understand what you mean by putting TF's in array, too.

Comment: Add another array that will hold those TFs. It's as easy as with strings, `tfArray.push(tf);` and then reference them from there, including removing in bulk.

Answer (score 0):

In your condition `if(tf.numChildren != 0)` the `tf` object is `null` since you never created it. That's why you're getting the `#1009` error.

On the other hand, in order to delete all items you should replace the `if (tf.numChildren != 0)` with `while (tf.numChildren != 0)`.

Comment: Did you create the `TF` object by calling `new`?

Comment: Yes, but it's within a loop that's within a function. One should be created every time the button is clicked.